# Regular Expression for null or Domain (Pattern) validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, dns

This is not working I am using following code to validate email for e.g

```
"email":{
"regex":"/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/",
"alertText":"* Invalid email address"},
```

On this way I want to validate text box by regular expression. It should be Null or valid domain name like Google.com, example.com.

Comment: _How_ is it not working?

Comment: What sort of validation/form handling *framework* do you use?

Comment: You've ask the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058484/regular-expression-for-null-or-domain-pattern-validation

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make it optional, that means empty string or a string that meets your regex, then try this:

```
^(?:[\w.-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})?$
```

I just put your regex into a non capturing group `(?:)`and make this group optional with the `?` after the group.

And I simplified your character classes, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is the same than `\w` and escaping is for the most cases not needed within character clases.

Answer (score 0):

Producing a regular expression to validate an e-mail address is far from trivial.

You probably want to read something like this:

http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php

Answer (score 0):

refer [regular expression for email validation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762977/regular-expression-for-email-validation)